# sql Сортировка по часто изменяемому столбцу

Tags: sql, postgresql, производительность

Мы знаем, что изменять значение индексируемого столбца это мееедленно. Что же тогда, производить сортировку без него?
Есть табличка записи которой имеют столбец с датой последнего их изменения, и она меняется, часто меняется, очень... и сортировка производится всегда только по ней.

Есть идеи как реализовать требуемый функционал, с возможностью использовать индексы?

Еще как вариант нагуглилось [pg_prewarm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgprewarm.html) - позволит "прогревать" базу со старта загружая в оперативку злощастный столбец.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Мы знаем, что изменять значение индексируемого столбца это мееедленно

Нет, не знаем. Почему "мееедленно"? Нормально обновляется. Имеет значение соотношение чтения и записи: может быть для вашего профиля нагрузки действительно лучше сортировать по требованию, если читаете сильно реже, чем пишете. От удивления даже начал гуглить. Ничего релевантного именно про "мееедленое" обновление индексов в pg не нашёл и никогда об этом раньше не слышал. Btree умеет не только хорошо искать, но и добавлять новые индексные записи.

Для интенсивной записи будет не лишним настроить автовакуум более агрессивным, чтобы мёртвые строки вычищались активнее.

`pg_prewarm` - это только на момент холодного старта СУБД. А для нормально работающего сервера все горячие данные и так будут в shared_buffers. Отдельно столбец прогреть нельзя. В shared_buffers лежат страницы данных, дефолтно по 4кб (может быть изменено только при компиляции). В каждой странице сколько-то записей таблицы целиком (кроме toast, хранящиеся в отдельных страничках) или индексные записи.

Может быть у вас несколько сотен тысяч транзакций в секунду и обновление индексов действительно при этом становится проблемой, я же об этом не знаю потому что не доводилось с такой нагрузкой работать. Но почему вы тогда упоминаете pg_prewarm и как вы собрались загружать в память отдельный столбец? И странно, что ни о чём таком не слышал на конференциях. Расскажите поподробнее о "мееедленно", очень интересно. Ссылки на pgsql-hackers весьма приветствуются.

Comment: Тревогу узрел тут: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50520/updating-an-indexed-column-performance-impact-in-sql-server

Comment: Провел тест на update 100 000 строк в двух табличках, в одной из которых проставил индекс на изменяемый столбец (int). Вроде разницы никакой. А если есть, то видимо не большая, и это хорошо =)